# Blueprint for building spring based applications

Tags: java, spring

Are there solid guidelines available on 'architecting' and building spring based applications?Something that goes beyond pet clinic sample application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build a small Roo application, and look how they (Roo team) did it. You will lern  a lot about who you can use Spring. - (For example: org.springframework.core.convert.support.IdToEntityConverter, tagx, ...)

*Ok that is more technic and design than coarse grain architecture but it is defently worth to do that before building an architecture that does not use the provided features.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a pretty good skeleton app builder called [AppFuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to read the book [Pojos in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394583) as it explains the foundations of how to build apps (design & architecture) in lightweight containers such as spring.